# Upload image to Firebase Storage Offline and then save that URL to the Real-Time Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am having a problem in that I have some data that gets saved to the Firebase Real-Time Database. Within the data are images (Photos and Signatures) that currently are being uploaded to Storage and the returned downloadUrl is being saved along with the data into the RT DB.

*Has anyone got any ideas as to how I can work around this while the device is offline?*

#### Platform: Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way around this.  It's not possible to complete a file upload while offline. There is also no way to get a download URL while offline.  You will have to complete this work while online so that you can populate the database correctly.